# True/False vs integers when dealing with booleans in Python

Tags: python, performance, boolean, boolean-expression

In Python `True` and `False` respectively have the same truth value than `1` and `0`.

Apart from style concerns, I was wondering if, from a time efficiency point of view, using `1`/`0` results in better performances than using `True`/`False`.

Comment: Highly unlikely to be better as 1/0.  But would be easy to test.

Comment: No efficiency difference whatsoever. There *might* be a difference between using `if x:` vs. `if x == True:`.

Comment: Lots of things have the same truth values, e.g. `[]` -> `False`, hence the idiom `if my_list:` rather than `if len(my_list) > 0:`. This seems like the very definition of premature optimisation; is there some *problem* you're trying to solve by switching? Note that the booleans are integers under the hood (in CPython, at least - `isinstance(True, int)`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually I have a friend of mine who persistently uses integers in place of booleans. I just wanted to be sure that there is no real reason to not use `True`/`False`.

Comment: Possibly that habit is from another language, it's totally unnecessary (and just makes the code less easy to read) in Python. But if you want to know why they do it, why not *ask them?*

Comment: From usage point of view, if you write `var == 0`, the person reading it will get the impression that `var` is an integer which can have any integer value. But if you write `var == True`, it is very clear that `var` is holding *boolean* value resulting in less chaos *(subjective)*. Though both will yield same result (as `True==1` return `True`), but it's better to use right type at right place

Answer (score 6):

In fact, *bool* inherits from *int*.

```
>>> bool.__bases__
(<class 'int'>,)
>>> True + 1
2
```

You should avoid micro-optimizations unless you profile your code before and after it. You may also try to use C-types in Cython if you need to improve calculation speed.